# How to supply locally running wsdl URL to online wsdl validators

Tags: web-services

This is my ipconfig details under command propmt .

```
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.46
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

I want to supply my wsdl  file to online WSDL Validator sites

So instead of using the below .

http://localhost:8080/Bayers/services/Tata?wsdl

I am using this

http://192.168.2.46:8080/Bayers/services/Tata?wsdl

My Tomcat server is  is running and i can see the wsdl file locally and i have turned off the windows firewall also .

But when i submited my wsdl to a online wsdl validator it is throwing me an 
But still i am getting error

```
WSDL Validation Errors FoundWe were unable to successfully validate the WSDL file at http://192.168.2.46:8080/Bayers/services/Tata?wsdl. 
We encountered the following errors:

WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL Retrieval error: Could not obtain data from connection
```

Comment: You should read a little more about private/public IP addresses and *address* your question on http://serverfault.com as it is not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

The online validator uses the url you provide for fetching the WSDL file for validation. But 192.168.2.46 is your computer only on your network (that is among computers connected to the same router). For the server that is validating, that IP address points to a completely different computer (or the address could be invalid for it) because it's probably connected to a different router.

If your computer is directly connected to the internet, you can expose your web server and provide that IP address. But I think this is unlikely. You probably have a router in between your computer and the internet. You can setup port-forwarding in your router and then use your router's external IP address to do this. That means, you can make any incoming requests to a certain port get automatically routed to your IP address. Google "port-forwarding" if you want to learn more about it.

But I believe that's too much effort if you just want to validate your WSDL file. You can just use offline validators if you prefer. Below are links to two validators but you can find so many if you just use google.

https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdlvalidator.html

http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2010/11/wsihero-gui-utility-for-web-services.html